# Use specs2.runner with own notifier from command line

Tags: scala, specs2

How can I call a self-written spec2 Notifier from the Java command line without using sbt.
I want to do this:

```
java -cp "testJars/*" org.specs2.runner.files "**/*" <here add MyTestNotifier>
```

Addition: In SBT we can do that, it works like this:

```
sbt testOnly * -- notifier MyTestNotifier
```

I want to do it without "sbt" because the test then starts faster.
I tried with (`--notifier MyTestNotifier`) at the end but unfortunately it didn't work

I read in the documentation that it works but unfortunately I don't know how

https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.9.5/org.specs2.guide.RunInShell.html#outputs

Comment: Can you try the option as a Java property? `java -Dspecs2.notifier MyTestNotifier ...`

Comment: Hello Eric,
thank you for answering my question.
i will try your suggestion for the next two days and then i will answer your question.
thank you for your time

Comment: It worked with a little tweak: `java "-DSpecs2.notifier=MyTestNotifier" ...`
Thanks, @Eric! Do you want to post this as answer (and I accept it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Java system property to pass the notifier name:

```
java "-DSpecs2.notifier=MyTestNotifier" ...
```